# Show that $P( A^c | B^c) = 1 + \frac{P(A \cap B)-P(A)}{P(B^c)} $

Tags: probability

I tried:

$$P(A^c | B^c) = 1 + \frac{P(A \cap B)-P(A)}{P(B^c)}  \iff \\
P(A^c | B^c) =  \frac{1-P(B)+P(A \cap B)-P(A)}{1-P(B)} \iff \\ P(A^c | B^c) = \frac{1 -(P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B ))}{1-P(B)} \iff \\ P(A^c | B^c) = \frac{1- P(A \cup B)}{1-P(B)}
$$

Am I doing this correctly? What do I do next?

Comment: What is the backslash

Comment: I'm sorry if this is silly, but why do your $A$ and $B$ have slashes through them in some places but not others?

Comment: I would guess that the slash means complementation. Not sure, though.

Comment: @RanWang presumably complements since the $\LaTeX$ is \not. I have edited for readability.

Comment: Likely meant to use \lnot  ($\lnot A$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use De Morgan's law
$$P(A^c \cap B^c) = P( (A \cup B)^c )$$
So
$$P(A^c|B^c) = \frac{P(A^c \cap B^c)}{P(B^c)} = \frac{P( (A \cup B)^c )}{1−P(B)} = 
\frac{1 - P( A \cup B)}{1−P(B)}$$
and complete your reasoning above.

Answer (score 0):

you can write

$$
P(A) = P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|B^c)P(B^c) \\
 = P(A \cap B) + (1-P(A^c|B^c)P(B^c) \\
= P(A \cap B) + P(B^c)-P(A^c|B^c)P(B^c)
$$

the result follows..